# Display search result of bootstrap datatables as a new table?

Tags: datatables

I am using bootstrap datatables follow this link: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/search/
However, when there are more than 1 page on the table, whenever I use the search function, it display the result of each page. How can I display all the search results from the first page like it is a new paginated table with filtered data.
The image can be see in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDA8U.jpg

Comment: It would be really helpful if you shared at least some of your code.  The DataTables should re-paginate the table when you use their built-in search function (although, I don't see their regular search field in your screenshot).  If you are using their API search function: `table.search(value);`, then you need to redraw the table as well:  `table.search(value).draw(false);`

Comment: @ReverendPete ah I see it, I wrote another function for search box. Thanks for the answer